# Standard visibility for abstract methods

Tags: java

This may seem like a silly question, but I'd like to know the "best practices" when creating abstract methods. Should their visibility be public or protected?

Even though a child class implementing the abstract method will be public, is it still advisable to  maintain the abstract method protected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on your use case. If the abstract method only implements some piece of a greater functionality that is available from a public method in your abstract class, then it should probably be protected. If it is a standalone method that can/should be called from another class, make it public.

Examples:

```
public abstract class Foo implements Closeable {
    public final void close() {
        // do whatever
        doClose();
    }

    protected abstract void doClose();
}

public abstract class Bar {
    public void read(byte[] b) {
        for(int x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {
            b[x] = read();
        }
    }

    public abstract int read();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the difference for public, protected and private:

[image: Modifier]

**For method if you set public it can be accessed to all classes within all packages in your project, if you set protected it just can be accessed to all classes within same package or sub class that extend the abstract class.**

For question no. 2: Yes, it is.

Comment: That's not what he asked. He asked what the best practices were for an abstract class, not for the definition of public/private/protected.

Comment: Yes, and he can decided what he want to choose public or protected based on my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what the method does. If it is something that represents the class (and subclasses) behavior, it should be public. If the method to be implemented by subclasses is internal and used by other methods of the base class (like defining an algorithmic strategy) it should be protected.